# Vectorizing complex assignment logic in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have some complex assignment logic in a simulation that I would like to optimize for performance. The current logic is implemented as a set of nested for loops over a variety of numpy arrays. I would like to vectorize this assignment logic but haven't been able to figure out if this is possible

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip

def reverse_enumerate(l):
    return izip(xrange(len(l)-1, -1, -1), reversed(l))

materials = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
                     [1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 1]])

vectors = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1]])

prices = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
demands = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])

supply_by_vector = np.zeros(len(vectors)).astype(int)

#go through each material and assign it to the first vector that the material covers
for m_indx, material in enumerate(materials):
    #find the first vector where the material covers the SKU
    for v_indx, vector in enumerate(vectors):
        if (vector <= material).all():
            supply_by_vector[v_indx] = supply_by_vector[v_indx] + 1
            break

original_supply_by_vector = np.copy(supply_by_vector)
profit_by_vector = np.zeros(len(vectors))
remaining_ask_by_sku = np.copy(demands)

#calculate profit by assigning material from vectors to SKUs to satisfy demand
#go through vectors in reverse order (so lowest priority vectors are used up first)
profit = 0.0
for v_indx, vector in reverse_enumerate(vectors):
    for sku_indx, price in enumerate(prices):
        available = supply_by_vector[v_indx]
        if available == 0:
            continue

        ask = remaining_ask_by_sku[sku_indx]
        if ask <= 0:
            continue

        if vector[sku_indx]:
            assign = ask if available > ask else available
            remaining_ask_by_sku[sku_indx] = remaining_ask_by_sku[sku_indx] - assign
            supply_by_vector[v_indx] = supply_by_vector[v_indx] - assign

            profit_by_vector[v_indx] = profit_by_vector[v_indx] + assign*price
            profit = profit + assign * price

print 'total profit:', profit
print 'unfulfilled demand:', remaining_ask_by_sku
print 'original supply:', original_supply_by_vector
```

**result:**

```
total profit: 80.0
unfulfilled demand: [0 1 0 0]
original supply: [1 2]
```

Comment: Scrolling code blocks can discourage casual readers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a dependency between iterations within the innermost nested loop in the second part/group of the nested loops and that to me seemed like difficult if not impossible to vectorize. So, this post is basically a partial solution trying to vectorize instead the first group of two nested loops, which were -

```
supply_by_vector = np.zeros(len(vectors)).astype(int)
for m_indx, material in enumerate(materials):
    #find the first vector where the material covers the SKU
    for v_indx, vector in enumerate(vectors):
        if (vector <= material).all():
            supply_by_vector[v_indx] = supply_by_vector[v_indx] + 1
            break
```

That entire section could be replaced by one line of vectorized code, like so -

```
supply_by_vector = ((vectors[:,None] <= materials).all(2)).sum(1)
```